# mysql create view from tabel and sorting

Tags: mysql, transform, create-view

I have a table with 
`id, number, lang, phrase`

For each number are multiple entries like

```
     1, 01, de, Hallo
     2, 01, en, Hello
     3, 01, fr, Salut,
     4, 02, de, Guten Tag
     5, 02, en, Good Day
     ..
```

The number of languages is fix

How can I create a view with the data arranged like

```
    id, de, en, fr 
    1, Hallo, Hello, Salut
    2, Guten Tag, Good Day, ''
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [MYSQL - Rows to Columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241178/mysql-rows-to-columns)

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Answer (score 1):

```
select number,
       max(case when lang = 'de' then phrase end) as de,
       max(case when lang = 'en' then phrase end) as en,
       max(case when lang = 'fr' then phrase end) as fr
from your_table
group by number
```